# Nuxt vue-router how to route to page dynamicaly

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

I got in pages the following structure

```
pages/
pages/portfolio
pages/portfolio/_detail/
pages/contact
```

If I navigate to in the URL to /portfolio all fine.

However I load my URLs from the CMS and there if the user wants to rename his portfolio slug and contact to for example slug: myportfolio, slug: contact-me then the URLs will not match. Hence there is less freedom to create slugs in CMS.

I can now from my API what type of page should be loaded. Each page will have a type of page. What I would like to is match the slug to the type and then load the page. As the API (CMS headless wagtail) will give me `[...{type: 'portfolio.PorfolioIndexpage', slug: 'myportfolio'} ... {type: 'contact.ContactPage'} ...]`

So ideally I want to write something like this.

`<nuxt-link :to="{name: slug, page: type}">` hence the url would be `/[slug]/` but the page to render would be [type]

Can somebody give some insight pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently its kinda easy.

you need to set up your folder stucture like this.

```
/pages/_portfolio
/pages/_portfolio/index.vue
```

then you can make your link as follows.

`<nuxt-link :to={name: 'portfolio', params:{portfolio: 'whatever-name-slug'}></nuxt-link>`